# FreeBSD handbook in PDF

Tags: freebsd

Could I get FreeBSD handbook in PDF without converting?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is a PDF version of the handbook in English at ftp://ftp.freebsd.org/pub/FreeBSD/doc/handbook.

For other languages, you need to select the language ftp://ftp.freebsd.org/pub/FreeBSD/doc/ and then browse to books/handbook directory.

The filename is **book.pdf.zip**.

Answer (score 1):

Latest version of FreeBSD Handbook in PDF format at:

ftp://ftp.freebsd.org/pub/FreeBSD/doc/handbook/book.pdf.zip

note: the above link can be slow to start download, so just give it sometime  :)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: I am pleased that you agree that it answers the question :)   perhaps of interest is http://meta.stackoverflow.com/